# Android: does a new thread ever implicitly get created?

Tags: android, multithreading

In Android development, does the system ever create a new thread?  If I never explicitly run code on a new thread (following how the docs say to [create a thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html)) do I have to worry about using techniques like `runonuithread()`?

Comment: Not normally.  Using an AsyncTask causes a new thread to be created (or at least causes work to occur on another thread).  Using an IntentService will cause threads to be launched, but a service shouldn't be touching the UI anyway.  And of course any library you use can do so, so if you pass a callback to a library its a possibility, see the library's documentation to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Android will only operate on one UI thread. If you need to do a big or slow task in the background then you'll want to create a thread (or even a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) possibly) to run the task without locking up the UI.

If the task needs to have a callback to change something when the thread has finished I recommend an [ASyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) they make threading very flexible and are easy to extend.